# Why is $L=\{xww^r \mid \text{ $x$, $w$ belongs to }(a+b)^+) \}$ not regular?

Tags: automata

If I have a language $L$ such that
$L= \{xww^r \mid \text{ $x$ and $w$ belong to }(a+b)^+) \}$.

Then  can't we write regular expression for this to be $(a+b)^+(ab+ba)$?
What's wrong in this regular expression ?

Also what if I have $L= \{wxw^r \mid  \text{$x$ and $w$ belong to }(a+b)^+) \}$ or $L=\{ww^rx \mid \text{$x$ and $w$ belongs to }(a+b)^+) \}$

Does the position of $x$ affect the nature of the language ?

Comment: What is your alphabet? You are using both $a, b$ and $0, 1$.

Comment: What's $w^r{}{}$?

Comment: So sorry alphabet is {a,b} only .

Comment: w^r represents the reversed string

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Take $x = w = a$. Does $xww^r$ match your regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: **J.-E. Pin** has suggested why your regular expression doesn’t generate $L$. To prove that $L$ isn’t regular (and hence that *no* regular expression generates $L$), you can use the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). If $p$ is the pumping length, let $w=a(ab)^p(ba)^p\in L$. If $L$ were regular, there would be a decomposition $w=xyz$ of $w$ such that $|y|\ge 1$, $|xy|\le p$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$. Since $1\le |xy|\le p$, while $|a(ab)^p|=2p+1$, we know that $xy$ has the form $a(ab)^\ell$ or $a(ab)^\ell a$ for some $k\ge 0$.

- Determine the possible forms of $y$.
- Then show that no matter what form $y$ has, the word $xz=xy^0z\notin L$.

Comment: For this particular $w = a(ab)^p(ba)^p$, could I not pick $y$ as simply $a$ and pump it? The result would still be $(a + b)^+ w w^R$? (I'm setting $\ell = 0$ in one of your forms)

Comment: @sprajagopal: If $y$ is the initial $a$, you get $(ab)^p(ba)^p$, which is not in $L$: $L$ requires that $x$ be non-empty. And if $y$ is an $a$ in $(ab)^p$, either it’s the first $a$, which has the same problem, or no suffix of the resulting word has the form $ww^r$.